# Most efficient way to implement two-stage sorting in a redis sorted set

Tags: redis, sortedset

What's the most efficient way to implement two-stage sorting in a redis sorted set? I.e. sort by x, and (only) when x's are equal, sort by y?

I have a sorted set of values that is to be sorted by *priorities* (between 1-10), but when priorities clash, it is to sort them *most-recent first*. How do you suppose this can be done (in the most performant way)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A viable solution is utilizing `priority+int(epoch_time)` directly as a `score`. Instead of between 1-10, priority should be between (1,000,000,000-10,000,000,000)

Comment: Good solution, but be warned: unicity between the values must be enforced programmatically. No unique value can exist with multiple scores.